# What does "a memory zone is balanced" mean?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

Recently, I begin to read Understanding the linux VM management, though it's out-dated. At the first chapter, I found some statements like: a zone is/isn't balanced. What does the word "balanced" actually mean? Thanks.

Comment: Its hard to tell out of context. Please paste the entire sentence.

Comment: @HAL, When the author explains the "pages_high" field in struct zone_struct, he says: After kswapd has been woken to start freeing pages, it will not consider the zone to be balanced when pages_high pages are free. I want to know the meaning of "balanced".